# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this and I cannot get it to work. Console.log logs null.
If I log before de update code it actually logs the item that im trying to edit. If I do it after the findOneAndUpdate() it returns null.

Edit 2:

I changed the mongoose method to findById and it worked. Still have one problem though. New code:

```
let promo = await Promo.findById(req.body._id)
      console.log('Promo findById(promoId) => ' + promo)
      console.log('Promo Fields => ' + JSON.stringify(promoFields))
      if (promo) {
        // Update
        const promo = await Promo.findOneAndUpdate(
          { promo: req.body_id },
          { $set: promoFields },
          { new: true },
          (err, doc) =>
            console.log(err + ' <--- err ///// ' + doc + ' <--- doc ')
        )
        return res.json(promo)
```

Output:

```
[0] Promo findById(promoId) => { _id: 5cee8b0134349e1eec482053,
[0]   title: 'Dos',
[0]   subtitle: 'dos',
[0]   desc: 'dos',
[0]   __v: 0 }
[0] Promo Fields => {"title":"Dos","subtitle":"dos","desc":"dos"}
[0] null <--- err ///// { _id: 5cee6bcbcfd3f11d580aa715,
[0]   new: false,
[0]   desc: 'dos',
[0]   subtitle: 'dos',
[0]   title: 'Dos' } <--- doc
```

The problem now is no matter what item from the list I edit it always updates de first one. Can it be an id mismatch? If I debug the id from req, I have the correct id from the item selected.. don't know why it behaves this way.
Last but not least here's the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  promos: null
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action

  switch (type) {
    case POST_PROMOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...payload,
        loading: false
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I was wondering if I could in the reduce make something like

```
state.promos.filter(promo => promo._id !== payload)
```

and then generate a new array with the payload item. I'm mixing concepts?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the `promoFields` referring to?

Comment: My bad @developing2020, already edited.

Comment: I read that it logs the item before the update. So can you add the output of a the console.log(promo) after the findOne?

Comment: @JackRed If I ran it before the `if(promo){` line, it logs the actual item

Comment: @JackRed and if I `return res.json(promo), console.log(promo)` all in the same line, logging it after, it keeps null

Comment: @NicolásRiccardi have you try to set the new option to false to see if it returns the old object? Did you check in the DB if the object is actually updated or if it doesn't change

Comment: @JackRed After passing true to new, it keeps returning null. It isnt changing in the DB. am i missing something here??

Comment: If I `let promo = await Promo.findOne(promoId);
      console.log('Promo findOne(promoId) => ' + promo);
      if (promo) {
        const promo = await Promo.findOneAndUpdate(
          { promo: promoId },
          { $set: req.body },
          { new: true }
        );
        console.log('Promo after findOneAndUpdate() => ' + promo);
        return res.json(promo);
      }
`
console returns this 
` Promo findOne(promoId) => { _id: 5ced4ba709b3112b003e5541,   title: '2',
   subtitle: '2',
   desc: '2',
   __v: 0 }
 Promo after findOneAndUpdate() => null
`

Comment: I asked you to set new to false, to check the old object and not the updated one

Comment: If i set to false, it returns the old object,`Promo after findOneAndUpdate() => { _id: 5ced4ba709b3112b003e5541,
  title: '2',
 subtitle: '2',
  desc: '2',
  __v: 0 }
`
but it doesnt updates in db

Comment: Can you try
`const promo = await Promo.findOneAndUpdate( { promo: promoId }, { $set: req.body }, { new: true } (err, doc) => {console.log(err, doc)})` ?

Comment: Wait, about your update, I didnt use mongoose since a moment, but you're replacing the whole object aren't you (not sure tho, if not, ignore the comment)? Why not using [findOneAndReplace](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndReplace).

Comment: Yes, it returns  null null. O.O

Comment: Tried with findOneAndReplace and its the same output

Comment: Well, are you replacing the whole object, or only some fields?

Comment: This is sent from front end form `const { title, subtitle, desc, _id } = formData`.

Comment: Another thing can you log promoFields before trying the update?

Comment: Promo Fields => {"title":"2","subtitle":"2","desc":"2"}

Comment: Try changing the variable name of `promo`.  Like so: `const updatedPromo = await Promo.findOneAndUpdate(
      { promo: promoId },
      { $set: promoFields },
      { new: true }
    )
    console.log(updatedPromo )
    return res.json(updatedPromo )`

Comment: It keeps returning null :((((((((( `Err, doc => null null`
`Promo after findOneAndUpdate() => updatedPromo = null`

Comment: Well, I feel like I'm missing something. Like something is off. But I'm sorry I don't see why you have this behavior. Did you try a normal update?

Comment: I did.. and it didn't work. It worked changing to the findById mogoose method. thought I have a new problem now. Edited the post. Btw thank you so much for all of your responses

Comment: If you have another problem, don't edit your post
Rollback the edit to the problem you answered and accept your answer (if possible, I don't know if there is reputation limitation)
And then make another question

So, this way, you will have more visibility, and if someone has the same problem as you, he will find a solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo!
It seems that req.body._id for some reason even though it was the Id from the desired editing item, it was not an ObjectId.

I `let promoId = mongoDb.ObjectId(req.body._id)` and then

```
promo = await Promo.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: promoId },
          { $set: promoFields },
          { new: true }
        )
```

:)! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$addToSet` in place of `$set` and it will maybe work.

Comment: Same output.. null. 
Can it be the models id?

Comment: do u debugg? maybe u missing some thing.